# Troubleshoot - ClientCertificateCredential authentication failed: The certificate does not have a private key

Tags: .net-6.0, azure-keyvault, private-key, client-certificates, x509certificate2

1. Az KeyVault, create Certificate
2. Download it

`az keyvault certificate download --vault-name [key-vault-name] --name mycert --file mycert.pem --encoding PEM`

3. Verify the Thumbprint

`openssl x509 -in mycert.pem -inform PEM  -noout -sha1 -fingerprint`

4. Install the certificate into my machine

- 1. `mmc.exe`
- 2. Click on "File" and then "Add/Remove Snap-in..."
- 3. Select "Certificates" and then click "Add"
- 4. Select "Computer Account" and then click "Next"
- 5. Select "Local Computer" and then click "Finish"
- 6. Click "OK" to close the "Add or Remove Snap-ins" dialog box
- 7. Expand the "Certificates (Local Computer)" node and then right-click on "Personal"
- 8. Select "All Tasks" and then "Import..."
- 9. Use the Certificate Import Wizard to import the certificate... Done!
- 10. Click "Finish" to complete the wizard.

Now try to get authenticate my .Net 6 Api against the Az KeyVault to get a secret using the certificate.

```cs
public static async Task<string> GetKeyValultSecrets(string key, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var keyVaultUrl = configuration["KeyVault:Vault"].ValidateArgNotNull("KeyVault:Vault");
            var thumbprint = configuration["KeyVault:CertThumbprint"].ValidateArgNotNull("KeyVault:CertThumbprint");
            var appClientId = configuration["KeyVault:AppClientId"].ValidateArgNotNull("KeyVault:AppClientId");
            var tenantId = configuration["KeyVault:TenantId"].ValidateArgNotNull("KeyVault:TenantId");


            X509Certificate2 certificate = null;
            using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, validOnly: false);

                if (certs.Count > 0)
                {
                    certificate = certs[0];
                }
            }

            if (certificate == null)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Certificate with thumbprint {thumbprint} not found in the local certificate store.");
            }

            string clientId = appClientId;
            var credential = new ClientCertificateCredential(tenantId, clientId, certificate);
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential);
            var secret = client.GetSecret(key).Value; // <----- Error!!!

            if (secret == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid Key Vault Key");
            }

            return secret.Value;
        }
```

and the error is:

```
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (ClientCertificateCredential authentication failed: The certificate certificate does not have a private key. 
See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/clientcertificatecredential/troubleshoot)'

2. MsalClientException: The certificate certificate does not have a private key.
```

however I have verified the `Key Usage` is `Digital Signature, Key Encipherment (a0)` but there is an exclamation point sign on it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To authenticate using a certificate **you need the (matching) privatekey** (and often a, or sometimes several, chain/intermediate cert(s) -- I'm not sure if this is needed for Azure). The privatekey is actually separate from the certificate, but MS (and MSians) often treat it as part of the certificate -- in particular, as a component of `X509Certificate2`. As [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/certificate?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-certificate-download) for your command says

> Download the public portion of a Key Vault certificate.

"public portion" means without the private key.

While there appear to be a few options for getting the key, the only one I believe will work with Windows is to download the *secret* in PFX/PKCS12 format; this includes the cert *and* privatekey, and *can* contain chain cert(s), both/all of which can be imported by MMC on Windows (and used by other things, like PS Get-PfxCertificate, openssl, NSS, gpgsm, Java, the list goes on). See
[Azure Key Vault download certificate with private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65097173/azure-key-vault-download-certificate-with-private-key) and
[Azure Key Vault - Download original PFX from Ket Vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74845992/azure-key-vault-download-original-pfx-from-ket-vault) .

PS: to run MMC/Certificates on LocalMachine, you can replace your steps 1-6 with  `certlm.msc` -- or just `certlm` since `.msc` is in PATHEXT.

Comment: thanks I'll test and see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the certificate as a secret from AKV to get access to the private key.

I use the following C# code to download it from AKV:

```
namespace Infrastructure
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension methods and helper methods to access the Azure Key Vault
    /// </summary>
    public static class KeyVaultExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Add Azure Key vault to the ASP.NET Configuration system
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config"></param>
        public static void AddAzureKeyVaultSupport(this IConfigurationBuilder config)
        {
            var builtConfig = config.Build();

            string vaultUrl = builtConfig["Vault:Url"] ?? "";
            string clientId = builtConfig["Vault:ClientId"] ?? "";
            string tenantId = builtConfig["Vault:TenantId"] ?? "";
            string secret = builtConfig["Vault:ClientSecret"] ?? "";

            Console.WriteLine("Adding AzureKeyVault Support");

            CheckIfValueIsProvided(vaultUrl, nameof(vaultUrl), sensitiveValue: false);
            CheckIfValueIsProvided(clientId, nameof(clientId), sensitiveValue: true);
            CheckIfValueIsProvided(tenantId, nameof(tenantId), sensitiveValue: true);
            CheckIfValueIsProvided(secret, nameof(secret), sensitiveValue: true);

            config.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(vaultUrl), new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, secret));

            Console.WriteLine("- Vault configured");
        }

        private static void CheckIfValueIsProvided(string value, string parameterName, bool sensitiveValue)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Fatal: - {parameterName} not found");
                throw new Exception($"Fatal: {parameterName} not found");
            }
            else
            {
                //To assist troubleshooting in production, we print out the first character for each config value
                if (sensitiveValue)
                    Console.WriteLine($"- {parameterName}: {value.Substring(0, 1)}...");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine($"- {parameterName}: {value}");
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Load a certificate (with private key) from Azure Key Vault
        ///
        /// Getting a certificate with private key is a bit of a pain, but the code below solves it.
        /// 
        /// Get the private key for Key Vault certificate
        /// https://github.com/heaths/azsdk-sample-getcert
        /// 
        /// See also these GitHub issues: 
        /// https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/12742
        /// https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/12083
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="config"></param>
        /// <param name="certificateName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate(IConfiguration config, string certificateName)
        {
            string vaultUrl = config["Vault:Url"] ?? "";
            string clientId = config["Vault:ClientId"] ?? "";
            string tenantId = config["Vault:TenantId"] ?? "";
            string secret = config["Vault:ClientSecret"] ?? "";

            Console.WriteLine($"Loading certificate '{certificateName}' from Azure Key Vault");

            var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId: tenantId, clientId: clientId, clientSecret: secret);
            var certClient = new CertificateClient(new Uri(vaultUrl), credentials);
            var secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(vaultUrl), credentials);

            var cert = GetCertificateAsync(certClient, secretClient, certificateName);

            Console.WriteLine("Certificate loaded");
            return cert;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Helper method to get a certificate
        /// 
        /// Source https://github.com/heaths/azsdk-sample-getcert/blob/master/Program.cs
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="certificateClient"></param>
        /// <param name="secretClient"></param>
        /// <param name="certificateName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateAsync(CertificateClient certificateClient,
                                                                SecretClient secretClient,
                                                                string certificateName)
        {

            KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy certificate = certificateClient.GetCertificate(certificateName);

            // Return a certificate with only the public key if the private key is not exportable.
            if (certificate.Policy?.Exportable != true)
            {
                return new X509Certificate2(certificate.Cer);
            }

            // Parse the secret ID and version to retrieve the private key.
            string[] segments = certificate.SecretId.AbsolutePath.Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (segments.Length != 3)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Number of segments is incorrect: {segments.Length}, URI: {certificate.SecretId}");
            }

            string secretName = segments[1];
            string secretVersion = segments[2];

            KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.GetSecret(secretName, secretVersion);

            // For PEM, you'll need to extract the base64-encoded message body.
            // .NET 5.0 preview introduces the System.Security.Cryptography.PemEncoding class to make this easier.
            if ("application/x-pkcs12".Equals(secret.Properties.ContentType, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                byte[] pfx = Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value);
                return new X509Certificate2(pfx);
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException($"Only PKCS#12 is supported. Found Content-Type: {secret.Properties.ContentType}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I'll test and see how it goes